# Bindings on self-written HandlebarsHelper?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i am trying add internationalization-abilities to my website.

I have written my own I18n.js which uses translation-objects out of the DS.store instead of its own (so there is a translation model and Ember preloads it on Application-start).

To get my translations into the Templates i have written this handlebars-helper

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function(key) {
    return Application.I18n.t(key);
});
```

so i could easily use it like:

```
{{i18n example_key}}
```

So far, everything works just perfect.
But the translations visible on screen are not bind to its translation-models.

If i change a translation in the administration-page which is places there too, i have to reload the page.

is it possible to add bindings between the helper and the translation model the helper have to display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [registerBoundHelper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper) instead of `registerHelper`. I don't even think `registerHelper` is part of the public API.

Comment: Thats right, i couldn't find a definition for registerHelper too. Based on my understanding of registerBoundHelper, it works the wrong way re-rendering when the translation-key-value(in my case) changes not when the translation-value changes.

Comment: In that case, just use [helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_helper). That's what I always use, and it works for what you're doing perfectly. `registerBoundHelper` must work in a way that I'm not aware of yet. (Note to self: find out.)

Answer (score 0):

What does `Application.I18n` look like exactly? In order to make the `{{i18n}}` helper refresh its content when something changes, it needs to observe something that is observable.

`Ember.Handlebars.helper` is useful if you pass an object with observable properties (see http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_dependencies). But if you only pass a key as a string, you'll have to set up the binding yourself in some way.